# Return fields in a custom format in serializer Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am very new to Django rest framework and I am looking to return a the model field serializer in a custom format.

This is the serializer:

```
class SubjectSkillLevelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SubjectSkillLevel
        fields = ["subject", "level"]
```

It currently returns this:

```
[
  {
     "subject": 1,
     "level": 1
  },

  {
     "subject": 2,
     "level": 1
  }
]
```

How can I make the serializer return a custom format like this

```
{
   1 : 1,
   2 : 1
}
```

What I tried:

```
def to_representation(self, value):
        return "%s : %s" % ("subject", "level")
```

But it obviously didn't work and just returned the strings.

Answer (score 0):

so i had a similar issue and wanted to change the return value for one of the fields. here is what I did.

first the field is an EmailField, so i created a custom EmailField class and added some codes to the **to_representation** method, like this

```
class CustomEmailField(serializers.EmailField):
    def to_representation(self, value: str) -> str:
        import re

        value = super().to_representation(value)
        regex = "^(\w|\.|\_|\-)+[@](\w|\_|\-|\.)+[.]\w{2,5}$"  # noqa: W605
        if re.search(regex, value):
            return value

        return ''
```

and then on the serializer class, instead of setting the standard EmailField for the email, I replaced it with the CustomEmailField class I created and it worked very fine.

```
 class FormSerilizer(serializer.Serilizer[Dict[str, object]]):
      email = CustomEmailField(allow_blank=True, source='user.email', max_length=200)
```

Hope this helps..